# Why am I unable to obtain an image from the stream in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

```
var image = await PicturePicker.PickImage(); 
 Image img = ImageSource.FromStream(image);
```

My code is as shown above. image is a stream returned from the picture picker and i fed it to the FromStream function in xamarin forms but it thorws me the following error Argument type 'System.IO.Stream'is not assignable to parameter type System.Func

Any kind soul able to help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of Image img. You should use ImageSource img

```
public ImageSource Imgsrc;
```

and try this code

```
 Imgsrc = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                        {

                            return image;
                        });
```

Actually this is how I do to load the images to my ViewModel.Hope it helps